# Why does my Perl sysread block when reading from a socket?

Tags: perl, sockets

I m doing a [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) in Perl 5.8.2  on AIX 5.3. As per the documentation, `sysread` is supposed to give 0 when it has read all read from filehandle.

In my scenario, the filehandle is STDIN and points to a socket. So I m basically doing a `sysread` from a socket. But I never get 0 from `sysread` and it just blocks, even after client has sent all data.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean "sent all data"? `sysread` returns zero when the handle encounters an end-of-file condition, not when there's no more data available *right now*. For a socket, EOF on read occurs when the other side has shutdown the socket for write. (Well, and `sysread` will also return `undef`, which is numerically equal to zero, if an error occurs such as a network timeout.)

Comment: i have sysread in a while loop to read data from a socket..
but it keeps blocking even after my client has sent all data..
sysread just blocks..

Comment: Your client is obviously not closing it's output filehandle, `sysread()` isn't psychic.

Comment: But i need to keep the socket open..because server has to send some data..
only then i can close it..
if i close the socket..then sysread works..
i need to make sysread non - blocking..

Comment: If this is a socket, client can `shutdown(socket, 1)` to signal it will not write anymore. sysread should return 0 after this occurs, as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`select`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#select) command (the one with the 4 arguments). It can tell you
whether there is any input to be read on your filehandle.